# EF6 Database First making Stored Procedure Async

Tags: entity-framework

What's the right way to run a EF6 stored procedure (database-first) in async mode?

I read about `ToListAsync()` but I don't see that available on stored procedure.

Also not sure if there is a different way to call the stored procedure when the actual call returns (#1) an OUT param or a (#2) list of items:

Case #1

```
 using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
 {
     ObjectParameter result = new ObjectParameter("Result", 
                                  typeof(global::System.Boolean));

     db.Login("email@email.com", "password", result);
 }
```

Case #2

```
 using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
 {
     var result = db.Contact_GetList("New York");
 }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is this in the context of an ASP.NET application? Say a controller method?

Comment: It's in a data layer for both a WebAPI and a MVC application. Each controller would call this DataLayer method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map stored procedures and start using it with out writing any initial code, this is how I did it.

1. create a new model with a new connection string that will generate the connection string automatically in the `web.config` file where the connection string is at (if you use a current connection string it may no work when you test the function for the SP on the model browser).
2. map your table and the stored procedures (you can test the stored procedures in the model browser).
3. create classes that represents the attributes retrieved by each stored procedure e.g if your stored procedure returns three columns A,B,C, then the class must also have these three columns as attribute with the [key()] on top of the column that is going to be the PK
4. now create your controller with the class created and a new `DbContext`
5. then copy the information in the data context generated for the model and pasted in the new context that you generate when creating the controller.
6. when you want to use the store procedures they will be ready on the db.context because you paste their code on you new db-context that you create when the controller was crated.

NOTE: I hope this is not confusing but I can use the stored procedures with out typing any code, please ask me if you need sample code or screen shots, your new db-context will not over write after you created

This is the stored procedure I map

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated from a template.
'
'     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
'     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public Class phone_CurrentConferences_Result
    Public Property AppointmentID As Integer
    Public Property AppTitle As String
    Public Property DateTime As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property [Date] As String
    Public Property Time As String
    Public Property Company As String
    Public Property Contact As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Office As String
    Public Property Lead_Director As String
    Public Property TBD As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Public Property conference As String
End Class
```

This is the same model with a primary key

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Conferences
    [Key]
    Public Property AppointmentID As Integer
    Public Property AppTitle As String
    Public Property DateTime As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property [Date] As String
    Public Property Time As String
    Public Property Company As String
    Public Property Contact As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Office As String
    Public Property Lead_Director As String
    Public Property TBD As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Public Property conference As String
End Class
```

This is the context generated by the EF

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated from a template.
'
'     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
'     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
Imports System.Linq

Partial Public Class DayMasterEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=DayMasterEntities")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Function phone_CurrentConferences(number As String, [date] As Nullable(Of Date)) As ObjectResult(Of phone_CurrentConferences_Result)
        Dim numberParameter As ObjectParameter = If(number IsNot Nothing, New ObjectParameter("number", number), New ObjectParameter("number", GetType(String)))

        Dim dateParameter As ObjectParameter = If([date].HasValue, New ObjectParameter("date", [date]), New ObjectParameter("date", GetType(Date)))

        Return DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(Of phone_CurrentConferences_Result)("phone_CurrentConferences", numberParameter, dateParameter)
    End Function

End Class
```

SO, when I create the controller I use the model with the `<KEY()>` and I create my own context that will look like this

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects

Namespace Models

    Public Class DayMasterContext
        Inherits DbContext

        ' You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        ' 
        ' If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        ' automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        ' For more information refer to the documentation:
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("name=DayMasterEntities")
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
            Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
        End Sub

        Public Property Conferences As System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Conferences)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then I copy the info in the context generated by the EF to my context

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects

Namespace Models

    Public Class DayMasterContext
        Inherits DbContext

        ' You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        ' 
        ' If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        ' automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        ' For more information refer to the documentation:
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("name=DayMasterEntities")
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
            Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
        End Sub

        Public Overridable Function phone_CurrentConferences(number As String, [date] As Nullable(Of Date)) As ObjectResult(Of phone_CurrentConferences_Result)
            Dim numberParameter As ObjectParameter = If(number IsNot Nothing, New ObjectParameter("number", number), New ObjectParameter("number", GetType(String)))

            Dim dateParameter As ObjectParameter = If([date].HasValue, New ObjectParameter("date", [date]), New ObjectParameter("date", GetType(Date)))

            Return DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(Of phone_CurrentConferences_Result)("phone_CurrentConferences", numberParameter, dateParameter)
        End Function

        Public Property Conferences As System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Conferences)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

So, now you can use this context to query

```
entConferences(number As String, [date] As Nullable(Of Date)) As ObjectResult(Of phone_CurrentConferences_Result)
```

or to get a `DBSet(of conferences)`

Here is a controller I have created with this technique

Look where I call my stored procedure

```
Dim conferences = db.phone_CurrentConferences(phoneNumber, currentDate)

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.Description
Imports BIWEBAPI
Imports BIWEBAPI.Models

Namespace Controllers.DayMasterControllers
    Public Class ConferencesController
        Inherits System.Web.Http.ApiController

        Private db As New DayMasterContext

        ' GET: api/Conferences
        Function GetConferences() As IQueryable(Of Conferences)
            Return db.Conferences
        End Function

        ' GET: api/Conferences/3053742500 
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Use to get the current conferences  selected by date
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="id">phone number and date separated by coma ",""</param>
        ''' <returns>conferences by date</returns>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        <ResponseType(GetType(Conferences))>
        Function GetConferences(ByVal id As String) As List(Of Conferences)
            Dim conferencelist = New List(Of Conferences)
            Dim dateAndPhoneNumber = Split(id, ",")
            Dim currentDate = ""
            Dim phoneNumber = dateAndPhoneNumber(0)

            If dateAndPhoneNumber.Length > 1 Then
                currentDate = DateTime.Parse(dateAndPhoneNumber(1))
            Else : currentDate = DateTime.Today
            End If

            Dim conferences = db.phone_CurrentConferences(phoneNumber, currentDate)

            For Each conferenceInQuery As Object In conferences
                Dim conference = New Conferences()
                conference.AppointmentID = conferenceInQuery.AppointmentID
                conference.AppTitle = conferenceInQuery.AppTitle
                conference.DateTime = conferenceInQuery.DateTime
                conference.[Date] = conferenceInQuery.[Date]
                conference.Time = conferenceInQuery.Time
                conference.Company = conferenceInQuery.Company
                conference.Contact = conferenceInQuery.Contact
                conference.Phone = conferenceInQuery.Phone
                conference.Office = conferenceInQuery.Office
                conference.Lead_Director = conferenceInQuery.Lead_Director
                conference.TBD = conferenceInQuery.TBD
                conference.conference = conferenceInQuery.conference

                conferencelist.Add(conference)
            Next

            Return conferencelist
        End Function

        ' PUT: api/Conferences/5
        <ResponseType(GetType(Void))>
        Function PutConferences(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal conferences As Conferences) As IHttpActionResult
            If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
                Return BadRequest(ModelState)
            End If

            If Not id = conferences.AppointmentID Then
                 Return BadRequest()
            End If

            db.Entry(conferences).State = EntityState.Modified

            Try
                db.SaveChanges()
            Catch ex As DbUpdateConcurrencyException
                If Not (ConferencesExists(id)) Then
                    Return NotFound()
                Else
                    Throw
                End If
            End Try

            Return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
       End Function

       ' POST: api/Conferences
       <ResponseType(GetType(Conferences))>
       Function PostConferences(ByVal conferences As Conferences) As IHttpActionResult
           If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
               Return BadRequest(ModelState)
           End If

           db.Conferences.Add(conferences)
           db.SaveChanges()

           Return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", New With {.id = conferences.AppointmentID}, conferences)
       End Function

       ' DELETE: api/Conferences/5
       <ResponseType(GetType(Conferences))>
       Function DeleteConferences(ByVal id As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
           Dim conferences As Conferences = db.Conferences.Find(id)

           If IsNothing(conferences) Then
               Return NotFound()
           End If

           db.Conferences.Remove(conferences)
           db.SaveChanges()

           Return Ok(conferences)
       End Function

       Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
           If (disposing) Then
               db.Dispose()
           End If

           MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
       End Sub

       Private Function ConferencesExists(ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
           Return db.Conferences.Count(Function(e) e.AppointmentID = id) > 0
       End Function
   End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Hi Cesar, sounds interesting but I'm not sure if you are saying that we should duplicate the classes that EF creates for us. Is that the case? Would be great if we could get the sample code you were mentioning. Maybe put a link to a zip file somewhere.

Much much appreciated

Comment: Yes you have to duplicate the classes generated by the EF because if you use those when creating a controller, you will get an error message saying that the model don have a primary key. I'll put some code

Comment: I'm not totally clear what the controller has to do with it, unless you are referring to strongly type the controller when you create it. I'm using a Data Layer approach so my stored procedure call is totally separated from controllers (not sure if that's relevant)

Comment: ok the controller need a model in order to create the controller and a context; you can not use the model if your store procedures don't have a class model with a primary key which is always the case when you retrieve a set from a store procedure the results has no PK that is why you have to recreate the model and the context in order to create controller. in the example I posted I show the model I created and the model create from the store procedure , if you still having issues understanding let me know I try to post a solution link.

Answer (score 3):

As per this [workitem](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1760) you would need to use `SqlQueryAsync`. Feel free to upvote the work item on the EF Codeplex site.

Comment: Can you use that with existing stored procedures? Also, I cannot seem to find that SqlQueryAsync method. Thoughts?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - what's wrong with recommending upvoting workitems on Entity Framework codeplex site? This helps prioritize work.

Comment: @Pawel: I have no problem with your edit. In its original form, you sounded like you were [inviting people to upvote your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts), which I figured sort of goes without saying if it's a good answer.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - after I rolled back I realized that it was not clear what I had recommended to upvote. Hence the edit. Thanks for keeping the answers clean!

Comment: Can anyone please let me know in what namespace the SqlQueryAsync method is coming from? I don't get that on my current dbContext.Database.xx ??

Comment: Link is broken.